# Crear eventos .ON personalizados en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Espero me puedan ayudar, porque quiero saber esto y no he encontrado nada útil en las búsquedas. Básicamente lo que quiero es hacer como un listener si es que así se dice, esperando a que otra función reaccione (o haga un callback, creo), y cuando reciba información, que se active. 
Tengo un socket, que recibe información, y quiero que éste al reaccionar le avise al evento **on chat** y le envíe parámetros también.
No sé si me explico bien, pero dejaré unas lineas de código como ejemplo:

```
connection.on("Chat"){
alert(evento.parámetro)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es utilizar la función `trigger`, dicha función ejecuta todos los controladores y comportamientos adjuntos a los elementos coincidentes para el tipo de evento dado, te anexo un ejemplo:

```js
$("#myButton").on("myCustomFunction", function(e, myStr){
        alert("Prueba "+ myStr);
    });
 
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
    
    var myStr = "de mensaje";
        $("#myButton").trigger("myCustomFunction", [myStr]);    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Click sobre el Botón!</label>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click Me!">
```

También te dejo otro ejemplo un poco más elaborado que encontré por si te beneficia:

```js
$("#example-section26 div").bind("HighlightEvent", function(e, color, colorTitle){
        $(this).html("Custom event triggered - " + colorTitle);
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });
 
    $("#btn261").click(function(){
        $("#example-section26 div").trigger("HighlightEvent", ["orange", "Color Orange"]);    
    });
 
    $("#btn262").click(function(){
        $("#example-section26 div").trigger("HighlightEvent", ["green", "Color Green"]);    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="#custom-event-example"></a>
<div id="example-section26">    
    <div>Build your own event</div>
    <input id="btn261" type="button" value="Trigger custom event(Orange background)">
    <input id="btn262" type="button" value="Trigger custom event(Green background)">
</div>
```

Anexo la documentación para que la consultes por si tienes dudas al respecto: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/. Espero sea de tu ayuda. Saludos.